# Getting MALFORMED error in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

This is my manifest file and I don't know why am I getting this error . Please help me out with this error. Everything is working fine, but the problem is the meta tags inside the applciation tags, if I write them outside the application tags then it crashes the app, and if I write them inside the application tags then I get the error "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest">

    <!--Permissions-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.MAPS.RECIEVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest.MAPS.RECIEVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x0020000" android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".profile"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".profile_update"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".sync_contacts"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".settings"
            android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:name=".synced_contacts_list"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_android_map_api_key" />

        <meta-data android:name="come.google.android.gms.version"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I think you should [learn this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectify Your <kbd>meta-data</kbd> **TAG** . It should be **`com`** instead of **`come`** .

**Wrong**

```
 <meta-data android:name="come.google.android.gms.version"/>
```

**Perfect**

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"/>
```

After that **Clean-Rebuild** and **Run** .